# How to set ngIf on chosen string in input?

Tags: angular, input

I want to show element if in input certain value is chosen

```
*ngif="currentSort=='category-1'"//in my div it doesnt work

currentSort: string = "most-0";
currentCategory: string = "family-0";

  options = [{
    value: 'most-0',
    viewValue: 'Najczęściej używane słowa'
  }, {
    value: 'category-1',
    viewValue: 'Kategorie'
  }, ];
```

How Do I achieve that? Thnks in advance

Comment: Not sure I really understand the question, but make sure *ngIf is a capital I not lowercase as you have it

Comment: if currentSort=='category-1' show my element,
if currentSort=='most-0' destroy my element

Comment: how do I achieve that?

Comment: Nah, now working your advice was solution. Thanks mate

Comment: No problem. Glad it's working

Comment: Domfx, do you know how to *ngIf on router link? it doesnt work *ngIf="[routerLink]="['/home']"

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. Use *ngIf not *ngif.
Kind regards